# ImageView bitmap is stretched after activity transition

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, scale, transition

[image]

Is there any specific reason why this is happening?

This is the image after the transition happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided any code to help us diagnose your problem, but your terrifying image (that looks like [Jim Carrey](http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11122/111228418/4546277-jim-carrey-11.jpg)) may be related to the [`tileMode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#attr_android:tileMode). Your image looks like it's exhibiting clamping.

Clamping is when the edge color is replicated if the bitmap for an `ImageView` is smaller in size than the `ImageView`. These are all the options, along with a suitable picture of Jim:

- disabled - Do not tile the bitmap. This is the default value.

[image: disabled]

- clamp - Replicates the edge color.

[image: clamped]

- repeat - Repeats the bitmap in both direction.

[image: repeat]

- mirror - Repeats the shader's image horizontally and vertically, alternating mirror images so that adjacent images always seam.

[image: mirror]

Since it looks like your `Bitmap` is smaller than your `ImageView` and I don't think you actually want to use any tile mode (just use the default of `disabled`), I'd recommend either:

A) Use `ImageView's` [`setScaleType()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType(android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType)) so that the `Bitmap` resizes to fill the `ImageView`, using the `centerCrop` value (though check [this blog](http://etcodehome.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html) for more examples), or...

B) Make your `Bitmap` larger

**(I'd recommend A)**

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't know about clamp.